# (2) There once was an item

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

...it has a very short life
But goes calmly and smoothly, little-to-no strife.
And even as it passes it becomes something new,
Changing shape constantly 'til there's nothing to view.
Depending where it passes you may see yourself in what's left.
Bruce Lee likes this version, to be like it, to be deft.
But at its birth it's hardy, something not okay to chew.
Except that's good advice many of us eschew!

Clarification: The answer is something you can hold in your hand, or with chopsticks.

Comment: I should probably change the title, I just did one of these before, and it wouldn't let me create another post with the same title.

Comment: I'm trying to create a format for these riddles, basically just a "what am I", but leading into it the same way each time/highlighting they're all basic 'items' in everyday life.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> Ice

Lots of credit to Ebe Isaac who was very close and inspired this answer!

---

...it has a very short life

> Melts quickly in room temperature

But goes calmly and smoothly, little-to-no strife.

> Ice melting is very smooth and steady

And even as it passes it becomes something new,

> Water!

Changing shape constantly 'til there's nothing to view.

> It all changes state until there is no ice left

Depending where it passes you may see yourself in what's left.

> You may see your reflection in the left over water, depending on where the leftover water is

Bruce Lee likes this version, to be like it, to be deft.

> From Ebe Isaac: A Bruce Lee quote: *'You must be shapeless, formless, like water.'*

But at its birth it's hardy, something not okay chew.

> Ice is solid and hard, and you don't want to chew it

Except that's good advice many of us eschew!

> Some people still chew ice, for instance ice cream, or just ice on its own

---

Answer (score 6):

Everything fits well to the answer

> **water**

Most lines are self-explanatory. As for the rest:

*Depending where it happens you may see yourself in what's left.*

> A puddle can be what’s left of a rainfall, on which you may see a reflection of your self. Credits to @BeastlyGerbil and @MacGyver88 for this point.

The answer is also attributed in Bruce Lee’s quote

> *You must be shapeless, formless, like water.*

Comment: You can see your reflection in it sometimes, depending on where it is and how flat the surface is?

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but it's too close to yours. +1

Comment: rot13(Onfrq ba gur eryrpgvba va jung'f yrsg, V jnf tbvat sbe n envafgbez be pybhq. Znlor lbh pna jbex jvgu gung.)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the clues, @MacGyver88. Made the edit required.

Comment: Very close, will add more detail/clues if needed, but specifically, how does water fit "But at its birth it's hardy, something not okay chew". Also notice the chronology when looking at the Bruce Lee line.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> An opportunity?

...it has a very short life

> Opportunities come and go, and you must quickly take hold of it or lose it

But goes calmly and smoothly, little-to-no strife.

> Opportunities come and go fairly quietly and you must be the one to uncover it

And even as it passes it becomes something new,

> A missed opportunity has the chance to be a learning point in life, where you learn a lesson and look again. A stumble can prevent a fall!

Changing shape constantly 'til there's nothing to view.

> As I said, opportunities come in many different forms and you need to take hold of them quickly

Depending where it passes you may see yourself in what's left.

> Depending when the opportunity comes in your life, it depends whether you grab hold of it or not, and in the future you see the consequence of whatever choice you had made back then

Bruce Lee likes this version, to be like it, to be deft.

> One of his quotes, "To hell with circumstances; I create opportunities."

But at its birth it's hardy, something not okay chew 
Except that's good advice many of us eschew!

> Children these days don't really get the point of taking an opportunity these days... what a shame. People know that you need to make use of good opportunities, but most are too lazy. And that is the difference between successful and normal people.